# How to remove whitespace when getting text from within XML tags?

Tags: javascript, xml

**XML:**

```
<topBar>
    <a class="navItem" href="/index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="navItem" href="/articles/">Articles</a>
    <a class="navItem" href="/about/">About</a>
</topBar>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
topBarItems = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("topBar")[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementById("navBar").innerHTML = topBarItems;
```

When I do this whitespace nodes are added to the HTML.

[image]

Is there anything I can do to remove the whitespace?

Comment: Is it really that whitespace is added, or does it just appear so in your HTML code viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
topBarItems = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("topBar")[0].innerHTML.replace(/\>\s+\</g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02pog3xq/) and the result in the HTML preview:

```
<topbar>
    <a class="navItem" href="/index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="navItem" href="/articles/">Articles</a>
    <a class="navItem" href="/about/">About</a>
</topbar>
```

If does not seem that whitespace is added to the HTML - it just might appear so because of the HTML code previewer that you're using. I'm seeing this in Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]